# APNS didRegisterForRemoteNotifications called before user allows notifications on iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on some iOS apps, all under the same publisher, that all have push notifications enabled.  When I call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes`, I get the user prompt to allow or disallow push notifications, but I `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` gets called with token data *before* the user chooses an option.  And it gets called again when they press OK.  Is this normal?

Also of note: multiple apps appear to get the same token when running on the same device.

Comment: I'm not sure about your main question, but as for the note - it's normal. All applications on the same device get the same device token.

Comment: May be you have already allowed that app earlier for receiving push notifications. Search your app in settings->notifications to check if it is already there.

Comment: @MSK - But if I've already allowed it, then it shouldn't be presenting the system prompt asking the user if they want to allow push notifications.  Am I wrong there?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I checked Apple docs and composed an answer for it. It was too long for a comment here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from Apple docs.

> When you send this message, the device initiates the registration
>   process with Apple Push Service. If it succeeds, the application
>   delegate receives a device token in the
>   application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: method;
>   if registration doesn’t succeed, the delegate is informed via the
>   application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: method.
>   If the application delegate receives a device token, it should connect
>   with its provider and pass it the token.

AND

> The first time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications,
>   iOS asks the user if they wish to receive notifications for that app.
>   Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again
>   unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at
>   least a day.

I think what you are observing is normal. There is no mention that `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`
will only be called if user grants permission. I think you can optimize it by caching device token in NSUserDefaults and in this method check if the new token not equal to cached token.

Comment: It seems illogical for me to get a token if push notifications get disabled at the system level.  But indeed, if I go into Settings and disable all push stuff for this app, I still get called back with a token.  I think you're right.

Comment: what is user enable push notifications when your app is in background. When you launch it you dont have token in your server and iOS will not call didFinishLaunchingWithOptions when you launch it from background.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, but I've just encountered this issue and it seems to be related to remote-notification background mode. `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is called on my iPhone before accepting push notification permission only when this background mode is turned on.